# How to switch the direction of a Django OneToOneField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I currently have a couple of models set up like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    child = models.OneToOneField(Child, null=True, blank=True)
```

Unfortunately this is wrong, because I want a delete on the parent to cascade to the child and not vice-versa, so I really should have them set up like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    child = models.OneToOneField(Parent)
```

Assuming that I don't currently have any orphan children, how can I set up the django migration such that my data remains intact? I'm using a Postgres database, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, add a `OneToOneField` to the child model, while keeping the original field.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    child = models.OneToOneField('Child', null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
```

I've set the related_name='+' so that the reverse relationships do not clash with the other field. You might find the data migration is easier if you specify a related name for one or both of the fields.

Create a migration for the new field.

Then create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to populate the new field.

Finally, remove the old field, and create a new migration.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much worked. The only catch is that `Parent` references `Child` before `Child` is defined, so I had to reference it as a string instead: `child = models.OneToOneField('Child', null=True, blank=True, related_name=='+')`. For some reason I'm still having trouble renaming the fields back to their original values while also removing `null=True`, but I can work around that, so this is good enough for now.

Comment: Good point using a string for `'Child'`, I've fixed the example above. Removing `null=True` from the new field should work, as long as you have populated all values first.